# Best option to store files and show them in communities

Tags: content, chatter-file, file-storage

What is the difference between CHatter files and Salesforce CRM content with regard to their usage in communities? What are known limits/ restrictions to use them in communities?

To manage Salesforce CRM content I see that Salesforce CRM content user license is required. But for chatter files it seems that no feature license is required.

I see that all these options use ContentDocument as backend. I am going to use remote objects to query files for community users.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

If you see above not much difference ,but common use case for the salesforce CRM content is as follows

1)You can share with customers directly via link through content delivery.This is awesome feature .Also you can track with content ,the no of times the file is downloaded or viewed .

2)Sharing can be controlled via publish but in chatter files you will need to share via group .